# Layout changing while scrolling a list view with two layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to use two layouts for my list view. While I am scrolling the list view, the layout is change to first one.
the code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  View vi = convertView;
  if (convertView == null) fll = flag.get(position);
  if(fll.equals("I")) {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conersation_replay, null);   
    TextView t1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mess1);
    TextView t2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    TextView t3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.time1);

    t1.setText(message.get(position));
    t2.setText(name);
    t3.setText(time.get(position));
  }
  else {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_custome, null);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mess);
    TextView t2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView t3 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.time);
    t1.setText(message.get(position));
    t2.setText(name);
    t3.setText(time.get(position));
  }

  return vi;
}
```

Comment: what do want still not clear bro ?

Comment: its like a messaging thread list view.Incoming message in one color and outgoing messages in another color.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make same control id in both the layout and do like below

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    chati = mlist.get(position);

    if(fll.equals("I")) {   
          // your layout here       
        convertView = ((Activity)mcontext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.conersation_replay, null);
    }else{
        convertView = ((Activity)mcontext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.conversation_custome, null);            
    }       

      TextView t1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mess);
      TextView t2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
      TextView t3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
      t1.setText(message.get(position));
      t2.setText(name);
      t3.setText(time.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: in if(fll.equals("I")) getting you string ?

Comment: put log your string and check your condion getting true or not

Comment: values are same but the layout is changing only at scrolling

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16642/discussion-between-ankitmakwana-and-akhil)

Answer (score 1):

If both layouts differ only in color,  then reuse convertView and adjust colors of elemtns (saves you view inflating).

If views are differrent ( say -  have different icons  and elements  ) ,  use ID of root element to determine kind of provided view  to dertermine whether it is of suitable type and inflate  only if it is not.

Also consider to use ViewHolder pattern to avoid lookup of text views:

http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Comment: but the image is also changing